# How do I replace the fork join pool for a Scala 2.9 parallel collection?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, scala-2.9, parallel-collections

I've been looking at the new Scala 2.9 parallel collections and am hoping to abandon a whole lot of my crufty amateur versions of similar things. In particular, I'd like to replace the fork join pool which underlies the default implementation with something of my own (for example, something that distributes evaluation of tasks across a network, via actors). My understanding is that this is simply a matter of applying Scala's paradigm of "stackable modifications", but the collections library is intimidating enough that I'm not exactly sure which bits need modifying!

Some concrete questions:

1. Is it correct that the standard parallel implementations interact with the fork join pool *solely* through the code in [`ForkJoinTasks`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks)?
2. I see that there's an alternative trait, [`FutureThreadPoolTasks`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.FutureThreadPoolTasks). How would I build a collection which uses this trait instead of [`ForkJoinTasks`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTasks)?
3. Can I just write yet another alternative (and perhaps a corresponding boilerplate class that mixes in [`AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.AdaptiveWorkStealingTasks) and somehow instantiate collections instances that use this new trait?

(For reference, all of the traits mentioned above are defined in [Tasks.scala](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_9_0_final/src//library/scala/collection/parallel/Tasks.scala#L1).)

Especially code examples are very welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html) is a document describing how to switch `TaskSupport` objects in Scala 2.10.

Answer (score 16):

Just to provide some more information on how things fit together (which I suspect you already know): the fork-join pool is "plugged in" via the `parallel` package object's `tasksupport` value which implements the `scala.collection.parallel.TaskSupport` trait.

This, in turn, inherits from `Tasks` (which you mention) and defines such operations as:

```
def execute[R, Tp](fjtask: Task[R, Tp]): () => R

def executeAndWaitResult[R, Tp](task: Task[R, Tp]): R
```

However, it's not immediately obvious to me how you can *override* the behaviour which is explicitly imported by the collections themselves by supplying your own `TaskSupport` implementation. For example, in `ParSeqLike` line 47:

```
import tasksupport._
```

In fact,I would go so far as saying it looks like the parallelism is definitively **not overridable** (unless I am very much mistaken, though I often am).

Comment: Confirmed - in the 2.9.0 version it's not meant to be overridable, though it's being considered how to allow this in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for this, @oxbow_lakes. It's curious that `FutureThreadPoolTasks` seems to be an orphan. @axel22, can you point me to which (if any) mailing list this has been discussed on?

Comment: How about changing this value using reflection?